# responsive side navigation bar in reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

Here is code given below please help me out as i am getting error over script tag and it running easily over simple html file but not in reactjs.

when i start the npm it says line no. this is having the error and it do not runs

> ./src/topbar/Navbar.js Syntax error:
>   C:/Users/root/mft/src/topbar/Navbar.js: Unexpected token, expected }
>   (34:62) 32 |  33 | function openNav() { > 34 |
>   document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px"; | ^ 35 |
>   document.getElementById("box1").style.width = "100%"; 36 | } 37 |

```html
import React from 'react';
import './Navbar.css';

class Navbar extends React.Component {
 render(){
  return(
    <div id = "navbar">
     <div class ="box">
      <div class="side" onclick={openNav()}>
    <div class="line-separator"></div>
    <div class="line-separator"></div>
    <div class="line-separator"></div>
    </div>
     <h1 class="right">A1MAN </h1>
      <div class="text">
      <h1>A1MAN </h1>
       </div>
       </div>
<div id="box1" class="back">
    <div href  class="closebtn" onclick={closeNav()}></div>

</div>


<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="">About</a>
  <a href="">Services</a>
  <a href="">Clients</a>
  <a href="">Contact</a>
</div>
<img alt="flower" src="http://www.byui.edu/images/agriculture-life-sciences/flower.jpg"/>
<script>

</script>

</div>
       );
 function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width="250px";
    document.getElementById("box1").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("box1").style.width = "0";
}

 }
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: ./src/topbar/Navbar.js
Syntax error: C:/Users/root/mft/src/topbar/Navbar.js: Unexpected token, expected } (34:62)

  32 | <script>
  33 | function openNav() {
> 34 |     document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
     |                                                               ^
  35 |     document.getElementById("box1").style.width = "100%";
  36 | }
  37 |

Comment: Is the code snippet taken from a .js file? Or an .html file?

Answer (score 0):

I think the cause of the error is a mismatch in closing curlies.

```
import React from 'react';
import './Navbar.css';

class Navbar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id = "navbar">
                ...
                <img alt="flower" src="http://www.byui.edu/images/agriculture-life-sciences/flower.jpg"/>
            </div>);
    } // <-------------------------------- This was misplaced

    // These methods belong on the component class, not inside a script tag
    openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width="250px";
        document.getElementById("box1").style.width = "100%";
    }

    closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("box1").style.width = "0";
    }
}

export default Navbar;
```

However, there are a few anti-patterns in the sample:

1. Don't use `<script>` tags: use [component methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).
2. Don't use `document`: either use state (e.g. `isOpen`) to apply a class or bind a width style, or use [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).